# Makefile with automatic dependency generation

Tags: makefile, fortran, dependencies, gnu-make

I'm reading *[Managing Projects with GNU Make](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/managing-projects-with/0596006101/ch08.html)* while trying to write a slim and general `Makefile` for my Fortran project. I'm lost at the point where the following code is presented,

```
define make-depend
  $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $(TARGET_ARCH) -M $1 | \
  $(SED) 's,\($$(notdir $2)\) *:,$$(dir $2) $3: ,' > $3.tmp
  $(MV) $3.tmp $3
endef

%.o: %.c
        $(call make-depend,$<,$@,$(subst .o,.d,$@))
        $(COMPILE.c) -o $@ $<
```

about which I read

> Now, the object file and dependency file are logically linked: **if one
>   exists the other must exist**. Therefore, we don’t really care if a
>   dependency file is missing. If it is, the object file is also missing
>   and both will be updated by the next build.

Well, I don't understand the part in **bold**; how is it possible to compile a source file (`$(COMPILE.c) -o $@ $<`) and generate its dependency file (`$(call make-depend,$<,$@,$(subst .o,.d,$@))`) at the same time? I mean, how can it work?

Maybe my Fortran experience misleads me, since I'm used to the fact that I can look in *one* source file to find which *other* source files it depends upon (looking for `USE` statements), then compile *those* source files (or repeating the process) and only after I can compile that *one* source file.

If needed, I can upload the short `Makefile` I'm trying to write, but it's obviously non-working. Specifically,

1. `make` pick one of the `.f90` files, say `some.f90`, creates its associated dependency file `some.d` with `$(call make-depend,$<,$@,$(subst .o,.d,$@))`, then fails when trying to compile `some.f90` with `$(COMPILE.c) -o $@ $<`, since `some.o` depends on `someother.o`, which is indeed listed in `some.d` at this point.
2. Running `make` again will result in an attempt to compile `someother.f90`, which will end in either
     2.1) success, if `someother.o` does not depend on any other `.o` file, in which case `make` would go back to step 1., picking another `.f90` file.
     2.2) or in error, but with `someother.d` being produced, and I should go manually to step 2.

Brutally, I keep on running `make` several times by `for ((i = 1; i <= 10; i++)); do make; done`, if ten times is enough.

This is the non-yet-working attempt:

```
# ====================================================================================================
FC = mpifort
FLIBS = -llapack -lblas
FCFLAGS = -ffree-form -ffree-line-length-0 -fimplicit-none -fdefault-real-8
# ====================================================================================================
PROGRAM := main
SRCDIR  := src
OBJDIR  := obj
MODDIR  := mod
DEPDIR  := dep
SRC := $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*.f90)
OBJ := $(patsubst $(SRCDIR)/%,$(OBJDIR)/%,$(SRC:.f90=.o))
MOD := $(shell echo $(patsubst $(SRCDIR)/%,$(MODDIR)/%,$(SRC:.f90=.mod)) | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]')
DEP := $(patsubst $(SRCDIR)/%,$(DEPDIR)/%,$(SRC:.f90=.d))
# ====================================================================================================
$(PROGRAM): $(OBJ)
    $(FC) $(FCFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS) $(FLIBS)
# ====================================================================================================
ifneq "$(MAKECMDGOALS)" "clean"
  -include $(DEP)
endif
# $(call make-depend,source-file,object-file,depend-file)
define make-depend
  ./dep-gen.sh < $1 | sed -e 's,\([^ ]*\),'"$(OBJDIR)"'/\1,g' \
                          -e 's,.*,'"$2 $3"': &,' > $(DEPDIR)/$(notdir $3)
endef
# ====================================================================================================
$(OBJDIR)/%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.f90
    @echo '************************************************************ target %.o'
    $(call make-depend,$<,$@,$(DEPDIR)/$(subst .o,.d,$(notdir $@)))
    $(FC) $(FCFLAGS) $(FLIBS) -c $< -J $(MODDIR) -o $@
# ====================================================================================================
.PHONY: clean veryclean
clean:
    $(RM) $(OBJ) $(MOD) $(DEP)
veryclean: clean
    $(RM) $(PROGRAM)
# ====================================================================================================
```

The bash script `dep-gen.sh` takes a `file.f90` file from standard input and sends to standard output the space-separated list of `files.o` files from which  the `file.o` file depends.

Comment: Do you know what the `-M` flag to your compiler does?

Comment: I read in the book what it does with `.c` files; days ago I tried to understand if it could be used to generate dependencies for Fortran file, but I found some thread on the web about problems with this, so I just stick to a bash script I made to generate dependencies for `make` (it generates what follows the `:`, whereas the target plus the colon is added in the `Makefile` itself). Do you think I should add my non working example? Actually it's not even minimal... not big, but neither minimal.

Comment: If you just want to understand the concept, rather than have a working Fortran version of dependency handling, then your attempted Makefile probably needn't be included.  I possibly just don't understand which bits of the process you don't quite get.

Comment: The logic for which the solution proposed in the book actually works should be the part of the quote I copied (but you can refer to the link to see the context), which I can't understand how it works. Let's start from clean: no source is compiled yet, so no dependency file exists yet; how can `make` take one source and "compile&generate-dependency"? It will certainly generate the dependency file, but it will likely pick a source which depends on other, and will rise an error when trying to compile it.

Comment: Btw, the solution to this problem is not urgent for me, since I have already a (much uglier) working `Makefile`, but if I understood the concept, I'd like to adopt this "cleaner" solution. So I'm asking you if you think it'd be worth it to copy my try even if I'm too far from understanding `make` deep enough to make the example minimal.

Comment: I never used FORTRAN, really, so maybe there are things about it that make these capabilities not usable with a FORTRAN compiler.  In particular I didn't understand your statement _Specifically, a dependency file is created and the compilation fails, but the subsequent compilation goes further thanks to the previously created dependency file_  What does that mean?  Why does the NEXT compilation go further because of a dependency file created by the PREVIOUS compilation?  A dependency file is (a) only for make, not the compiler, and (b) only relevant to its specific file not other files.

Comment: I think perhaps if you showed the makefile you have and the commands it invoked and the errors you got, it might help either someone with make experience or FORTRAN experience help you.

Comment: It is 2018 and `make` is a very old system not ever designed for Fortran. Just ditch it and use something developed in this century. I use scons others are using cmake or waf, I am sure there is even more out there.

Comment: @VladimirF Any reason to believe that CMake will do a better job here ? Because ultimately one of the ways to use it is to generate a (set of) Makefile, which you can do yourself. I don't dislike CMake, but I think if it can find a make-ish way to make it work, then OP can find it by himself without CMake.

Comment: As I said, I do not use cmake. Make requires too much recompiling when you change something.

Comment: @MadScientist, I tried to better explain the process; hope it's clearer now.

Comment: @VladimirF Only if you don't write your Makefile properly. The whole purpose of `make` is to build exactly what is needed, no more no less. That's the whole point of dependency files. However this was clearly designed for compiler that can generate those files, I don't know if FORTRAN can do that.

Comment: @Tim I doubt `make` is able to recognize that the interface did not change, just the internals, so even if it is a change in the dependency, it does not affect dependent modules.

Comment: It's correct make doesn't recognize this because it's not targeted for a specific language, it's general purpose which is why it takes in account the file timestamp and not the internals. But CMake will do exactly the same with C/C++ anyway. I don't know if there's a clever build manager that takes this kind of thing in account, and I don't know if I would trust it.

Comment: VladimirF, Tim, I suspect you are talking past each other. In particular you seem to be using the word *"internals"* to mean two different things.